# NSString to char my[16]

Tags: ios, nsstring, char

I am having NSString like :

```
NSString *str = @"225,0,190,169,236,236,113,97,43,102,217,8,113,201,50,45";
```

how can i convert it to char array as shown below:

```
char keyPtr[16] = {225,0,190,169,236,236,113,97,43,102,217,8,113,201,50,45}
```

can anyone help!

Thanks

Comment: `componentsSeperatedByString` to get each "string number", then put each one into the char. Is that where you where blocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *input = @"225,0,190,169,236,236,113,97,43,102,217,8,113,201,50,45";
char output[16];

NSArray *elements = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSAssert([elements count] == 16, @"Input has wrong number of elements");
unsigned index = 0;
for (NSString *element in elements) {
    int value = [element intValue];
    NSAssert(value >= 0 && value <= 255, @"Element is invalid");
    output[index++] = (char)value;
}
```

Note: You probably should be using a `int[]`, and not `char[]`, for `output`.

Comment: You can see 236(input) value which will store as unexpected.(due to char range -127 to 128)

Comment: @Mani Only if `char` is a *signed* value, which is not always the case, but I agree and I mention the array should be `int` and not `char`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"225,0,190,169,236,236,113,97,43,102,217,8,113,201,50,45";
NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Then use this in a for loop or something to add to your char array:

```
char* myLilChar = [[array objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String];
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be as you said, use below

```
NSString *str = @"225,0,190,169,236,236,113,97,43,102,217,8,113,201,50,45";
NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
unsigned char keyPtr[array.count];
for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
    keyPtr[i] = (unsigned char)[[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

Comment: @trojanfoe I've updated my answer. what does mean? I didn't get it.